# How to use 'schedule' and 'run' together

Tags: python, schedule, bottle

I have a schedule script running a job with:

```
schedule.every(3).seconds.do(jobCheckSmth)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I wanted to use web interface to check on it's status instead of print() on the CLI with

```
run(host='localhost', port=80, debug=True)
```

But it blocks code execution so I have to Ctrl-C to break *webserver* loop to continue to run *while* loop

```
Bottle v0.12.18 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:80/ Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Comment: I'm investigating threading to do the job...

Comment: Threading acts wiered... please advise

Comment: I guess that you will have to run your webserver on a separate process and feed it with your main process with some external update (json file or DB)

Comment: Looks so @SebastienD

Comment: You need to learn about asynchronous design, .e.g. https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works really well for me using `gevent` to turn bottle into async.  It's either this, or you have to run `schedule` in it's own thread outside of your bottle app. But honestly you should be doing this.

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey,spawn as gspawn, sleep as gsleep, socket, signal_handler as sig
monkey.patch_all()
import signal
import arrow
from bottle import Bottle, static_file, get, post, request, response, template, redirect, hook, route, abort
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler

def start():
    def start_thread():
        set()
        while 1:
            try:
                schedule.run_pending()
            except:
                logger.exception('Scheduler Exception')
            gsleep(5) # This is the polling cycle for pending jobs
    print('Scheduler Started...')
    gspawn(start_thread)

def sample():
    gspawn(jobCheckSmth)

def set():
    # schedule.every(180).seconds.do(func)
    schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(sample)
    logger.info('Started Schedule at {}'.format(arrow.now()))

@get('/')
def app():
    return 'Hello World!'

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler.start()
    botapp = bottle.app()
    server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", int(port)), botapp , handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    def shutdown():
        print('Shutting down ...')
        server.stop(timeout=60)
        exit(signal.SIGTERM)
    sig(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
    sig(signal.SIGINT, shutdown)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed example. I'll try to implement the idea. Will keep you posted. Thanks again!

Comment: Marked your reply with upvote. My rank is not enough yet to show it. How do I accept yours as working?